# css3 doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
  <head>
    <title>Minimal XHTML 1.1 Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p.test {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="test">This is a minimal <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11">XHTML 1.1</a> document.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I try to validate it here:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options

I get the following error:

p.test  Parse Error [empty string]

Comment: Did you click the "More Options" link and select Profile: css3?

Comment: css3 will work in future. just drink a tea and wait

Comment: @Tomkay - A lot of CSS3 works just fine in modern browsers; that is, everything but IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation has nothing to do with whether any particular property works in any browser. It only indicates whether the syntax and content follows the standard. As this error states, it does not exist in CSS 2.1 but it does exist in CSS3. You can select CSS3 from the "More Options" drop down box

Comment: But in the firefox error console, I keep getting Declaration dropped for a lot of css3 things, can I just ingore those?

Comment: @NomenNescio I don't get that from what you post.

Comment: Firefox (and all other browsers) will implement more and more properties as time progresses. Currently, most browsers support most of CSS2.1 and a sizeable portion of CSS3. But the standard itself isn't finalised yet, so you can't count on all browsers having implemented all of CSS3 any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current version of the spec does NOT contain text-overflow.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/

Comment: yes, but this is not a final draft. I would say the jigsaw validator don't use this version. You can use it but is not valid for the validator.